# Google analytics API C#

Tags: c#, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, visitor-statistic

I'm currently implementing a pageview counter on some webpages using the Google Analytics API. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use the Google API. Could someone post some examples how to use the API?

I searched the mighty internet but I didn't found any tutorials who guided me through the API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thijs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not use the GData Apis suggested by Haythem, as Google has release a new breed of Apis ([Google Api Explorer](https://code.google.com/apis/explorer)), you can see the entry for [Google Analytics](https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=analytics&_v=v3).

I assume as they have released a new way of doing things they will at some stage turn off the GData Apis so if you are building a new application I would build against the new API not the 
old GData Api.

There is a good introduction to using the Google Analytics at http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/v3/mgmtGettingStarted.html there is also a page with links to [Examples and Libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/v3/mgmtLibraries.html) for using the Analytics Api.

Comment: This is a refinement of a answer previously deleted by moderator for not answering the question directly. Hopefully this go at it does a better job of answering the question. I'm not trying to take the mickey, I think this answer adds useful information, if community or moderators disagree I wont attempt to answer this again.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it. Thank you for your contribution. :)